# Matching only one space and A-Za-z!#$%&'()-@_{} 123456780

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, string-matching, nsregularexpression

I am attempting a string matching function that has the following requirements.

```
   Only space, alphanumeric characters, and !#$%&'()-@_{} are valid.
```

The function I have put together looks like.

```
import re
def string_match(tested_string):
    match = re.match("^[A-Za-z!#$%&'()-@_{} 123456780]*$", tested_string)
    return match is not None
```

The pattern matching works with more than one space. 
Where I only want it to pass for one space.

For example.

```
print(string_match("b "))
print(string_match("b  "))
```

My desired output is

```
True 
False
```

Instead, it outputs

```
True 
True
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the `-` in a character class must be put at the start or end, or it creates a range and might match more than you want or invalidate the whole pattern.

You missed a `9` in the `1234567890`. Note it can be written as a `0-9` range to shorten the pattern.

To fix the issue, use either of the two approaches.

**Split the character class and use an optional grouping**

You may take out the space and split the character class in two parts without a space, putting a space and the part of the character class after another part of the character class inside a quantified grouping:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'()@_{}-]*(?: [A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'()@_{}-]*)?$
```

Look:

- `^` - start of string (you can omit it in `re.fullmatch` and `re.match`)
- `[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'()@_{}-]*` - 0+ letters, digits and a char from `!#$%&'()@_{}-`
- `(?: [A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'()@_{}-]*)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of

  - - a space
  - `[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'()@_{}-]*` - same as above
- `$` - end of string (you can omit it in `re.fullmatch`)

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MZ9FB3/1).

**Add a negative lookahead**

You may simply tell the regex engine when at the start of the string that you do not need to match anything if there are two spaces in the string:

```
^(?!(?:[^ ]* ){2})[A-Za-z0-9 !#$%&'()@_{}-]*$
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/MZ9FB3/2). Note that to define the same pattern for any whitespace you may use

```
^(?!(?:\S*\s){2})[A-Za-z0-9\s!#$%&'()@_{}-]*$
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MZ9FB3/3). (The demos are a bit different because a single multiline string is used for the demo purpose, to avoid overflowing the newline.)

**Python usage**

```
import re
def string_match(tested_string):
    return re.fullmatch(r"(?!(?:\S*\s){2})[A-Za-z0-9\s!#$%&'()@_{}-]*", tested_string)
```

Or,

```
import re
def string_match(tested_string):
    return re.match(r"[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'()@_{}-]*(?: [A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'()@_{}-]*)?$", tested_string)
```

See the [Python demo online](https://ideone.com/e7AJLI).